# Image data is not fetched in entirety when reading an image of unknown size

Tags: c, file, io

I have an image file that I'm trying to read and store in a buffer `buffer`.

However, I'm only picking up the first few characters, and not the entire file.
I also don't know the total length of the file, so I unfortunately can't tell it to read X number of characters.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char *data;
    read_file("Dragon.png", &data);
    printf("%s", data);
}

int read_file(char *file, char **buffer) {

    FILE *file_r = fopen(file, "rb");
    
    if (file_r != NULL) {
    
        fseek(file_r, 0, SEEK_END); // Set file position to end of file
        unsigned long file_size = ftell(file_r); // Record the position (find the total size of the file)
        fseek(file_r, 0, SEEK_SET);  // Move back to the beginning to begin reading
        
        *buffer = malloc(file_size + 1); // Allocate buffer memory
        fread(*buffer, 1, file_size, file_r);
        fclose(file_r);
        
        return file_size; // File read and passed
    }
    return -1; // File not found (or other error)
}
```

When running:

```
$ gcc read-file.c -oa
$ ./a
�PNG
�
$
```

I have no idea how to fix this.  How should I proceed?

Comment: `printf("%s", data);` if the buffer has a 0 in it it will stop printing there.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Ah OK.  That's probably it then.  In my actual code I'm using `strcat(*data, buffer);` so I assume it the same case there too.  How do I fix it?  Initerate through `file_size` as I append everything?

Comment: As Johnny pointed out, `data` is _binary_ so it's not really valid/useful to do `printf`. You could print the values in a loop with (e.g. `printf(" %2.2X",data[i]);`). Also, it's best to check the return value of `fread` and _loop_ if the read stopped short of the full amount

Comment: Yes, same issue. You can use `memcpy` instead.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  Thank you very much.  That's exactly what I needed to do